# Pivot tables - column alias not recognized in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am trying to produce a pivoted table. [image: I have a picture of the query and data here.]

I have aliased column names, since the columns are being aggregated.

Why isn't my alias usable?

[image: Here is a picture of the error message.]

Comment: Because you're using Enrollment in your aggregation i.e. `sum(Enrollment)` so it's not available in the final select.

Comment: @bluefeet Perfect. Thank you! First time using pivot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are aggregating the data in the `Enrollment` column via `sum(Enrollment)` that column is no longer available for the final select list. Remove it from the final select list and the query should work without any issues.

The thing to remember when using a `PIVOT` is columns you use inside of the statement are being replaced because you are converting the values into new columns. In the case of your query, both the `Enrollment` and `ProgramType` are not available in the final select.